# Ipython histogram - replace old histogram with new one

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ipython, histogram

I have a program in ipython which has two dropdown menus and a button.   When I hit the button I want to search a dataframe using information from the dropdowns and then create two histograms side by side.   I have tested my code on retrieving information from the dataframe and this is working fine and I can make the new histograms I need.   What I am looking to do is when a new selection is made from the dropdowns for the old histograms to be updated with new ones.   At the moment they are just appearing below the previous ones.

How would I do this?

Tldr:  how to update an existing diagram with new info?

EDIT:  Below is a summary of my code

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

#  Function to find results
def search(btn):
    plt.clf()
    ax1.hist(results_df1.COLUMNA.dropna().values, bins=180/5, range=(-60,120))
    ax2.hist(results_df4.COLUMNA.dropna().values, bins=180/5, range=(-60,120))
    plt.show(fig)

#  Button to enter information
btn = widgets.Button(description="Update")
btn.on_click(search)
display(btn)
```

Comment: Could you post what code you have? And it will be impossible to enhance without seeing what is existing.

Comment: No problem - added a summary of the code I have :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pylab as p 
from notebook import *
from ipywidgets import *
from ipywidgets import interactive
%matplotlib inline


def search():
    fig = p.figure(figsize=(10,5))

    p.subplot(121)
    p.hist(np.random.rand((50)) )

    p.subplot(122)
    p.hist(np.random.rand((50)) )
    p.show()
    return HTML()  # makes it flicker free

interact_manual(search )
```

The above would work for me. I'm redrawing the whole graph, though, not just updating the data, which could be done also :
`l,=p.plot(...)` to make the graph, 
then `l.set_ydata(...)` inside the update loop.